# Which analysis method to choose: two between club variations need to be explained using many other variables? Scheme provided

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling

I am a master student and need help in approaching the following problem.

I have a large dataset about athletes from different professional level clubs (athlethes nested in clubs), their performance (game score and probability of injury) and methods they used in their training (many variables). There are 15 different clubs that did not play each other (independent), number of athletes varies from 50-150.

We found high variability in game score (club performance score) and probability of injury between the clubs, and would like to find a suitable analysis method to explain this variability. Or in other words, we would like to know which methods were associated with good/bad game score or which with the lowered/increased probability of injury.

**I made a scheme of this data and study question:**
[image]

**QUESTIONS:**

1) My limited understanding says that simple correlations between two variables is not a good solution here as athletes concurrently used other methods that need to be taken account (fixed?) in analysis?

2) Some version of SEM may be suitable, but there seems to be multiple options? Please help me to choose a suitable test for analysis.

Comment: This sounds to me like a mixed model  - you have athletes nested within clubs. Or is it games nested within clubs? Do clubs play each other? If so, you have a very complex cross-classified structure (or maybe a multiple membership model).

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Athlethes nested within clubs. Clubs are independent as they did not play each other. Is it wrong to just check correlations between all these variables using their club means with correlogram? E.g. probability of injury and proportion of athletes received training method 5? There are 15 different clubs.

Comment: One additional factor may also be important. Athletes from different clubs may have used  the same facility (specialist) for certain specific training methods (E.g. training method 5).

Comment: aggregating to the club level is not horribly wrong, but it's not the most powerful approach.